# Time complexity of double loop when i is outer loop and inner loop starts with j=i+1

Tags: arrays, loops, time, double, complexity-theory

I am trying to get more clarity on the complexity of the algorithm I wrote below:

```
left = 1
right = 1

for i=0; i < array.len; i ++:
        j = i+1
        for j; j < array.len; j++:
             right *= array[j]
        tmp[i] = array[idx]
        left *= array[idx]
        right = 1
return tmp
```

If we define array size to be n, then O(n) for the outer loop, but inner loop doesn't really iterate n-1 times all the time, only the first time when i=0.

So, what would be the complexity? 
O(n) for the outer loop and 
O(n-j) for the inner loop? 
So, maybe O(n(n-j)) ? Which ends up being O(n^2)?

Help please.

Comment: you are right :)

Answer (score 3):

yes, O(n^2) is the time complexity.  first loop runs n times.  second loop runs n times for each iteration of the first loop.  n * n = n^2

Comment: Be careful with stating that "second loop run n times for each iteration" – `j` starts at `i + 1` instead of 0.

Comment: ahh, yes, fair point. though (n) * (n -1) would still be considered n^2. (n^2 - n and we just drop the n)

Comment: Yes that's correct (apart from a missing factor of 1/2); however it is good practice to show the full derivation, so as not to mislead the asker into thinking that naive multiplication will work for an arbitrary time complexity problem.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog which would be the complete big-O notation for this algorithm?
Which would be the missing factor of 1/2?

Comment: @knowKnothing "complete" big-O notation is still `O(n^2)`. However the "precise" number of executions of the inner loop is `n * (n - 1) / 2`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thx, I understand the n*(n-1), but the 1/2 factor is a bit of a mystery for me in this case.
However, I know in some cases like iterating an array from both ends start_idx and last_idx, and start_idx++ and last_idx-- would yield a complexity of O(n/2).
Is this similar?

[EDIT] nvm, I believe a similar halving of the iteration in the inner loop is done by j = i +1 above. 
Thanks all.

Comment: @knowKnothing if you're unsure of where the 1/2 factor comes from, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). But it is just a multiplicative constant factor so is discarded by O-notation.